# AWS failed to create and update stack (proactive events API) while creating Alexa skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, yaml, aws-cloudformation, alexa-skills-kit

I'm setting up a skill that includes the proactive events API for an Amazon Alexa skill that I'm creating. I'm following this [guide](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-proactive-events). The two important files for this issue are the deploy.sh and pingme.yaml

When I run the deploy.sh file in git bash this is the output

```
Waiting for changeset to be created..
Waiting for stack create/update to complete

Failed to create/update the stack. Run the following command
to fetch the list of events leading up to the failure
aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name PingMe
```

When I run the command it just repeats a sequence of json code that follows a similar format (albeit with different values) expect for this one part

```
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource handler returned message: \"Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: SOME_ID)\" (RequestToken: SOME_TOKE, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)",
```

I'm kind of stuck on how to use AWS, the only output that I get in the CLOUD_FORMATION console is ROLLBACK_COMPLETE with a red X next to it (meaning its just an empty stack). I guess its saying that I'm not in the right region even though the guide says to use the Virginia (USA) location?

What I'm thinking is that the user I created for my AWS account is missing something in the permission policies? When I setup the AWS CLI it asked for an access and secret key. I'm pretty sure some new roles were created automatically when I ran the script. (if that's possible)

Running the script definitely did something for my AWS user since it shows activity from when I first ran the script.

```
$ aws cloudformation describe-stack-events --stack-name PingMe
{
    "StackEvents": [
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "963a5aa0-a3dd-11ed-bcfe-0abfc587127d",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "PingMe",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:42.181000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_COMPLETE"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "DatabaseTable-DELETE_COMPLETE-2023-02-03T16:12:41.562Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseTable",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "askPingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:41.562000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"TableName\":\"askPingMe\",\"AttributeDefinitions\":[{\"AttributeType\":\"S\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}],\"ProvisionedThroughput\":{\"WriteCapacityUnits\":\"5\",\"ReadCapacityUnits\":\"5\"},\"KeySchema\":[{\"KeyType\":\"HASH\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunctionRole-DELETE_COMPLETE-2023-02-03T16:12:39.141Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunctionRole",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:39.141000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ManagedPolicyArns\":[\"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole\"],\"Policies\":[{\"PolicyName\":\"askLambdaFunctionRolePolicy0\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"dynamodb:GetItem\",\"dynamodb:PutItem\",\"dynamodb:UpdateItem\",\"dynamodb:DeleteItem\"],\"Resource\":[\"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/askPingMe\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\"}]}}],\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"lambda.amazonaws.com\"]}}]},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunctionRole-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:12:36.955Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunctionRole",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:36.955000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ManagedPolicyArns\":[\"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole\"],\"Policies\":[{\"PolicyName\":\"askLambdaFunctionRolePolicy0\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"dynamodb:GetItem\",\"dynamodb:PutItem\",\"dynamodb:UpdateItem\",\"dynamodb:DeleteItem\"],\"Resource\":[\"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/askPingMe\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\"}]}}],\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"lambda.amazonaws.com\"]}}]},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunction-DELETE_COMPLETE-2023-02-03T16:12:36.093Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunction",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "ask-custom-PingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:36.093000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Role\":\"arn:aws:iam::879047331400:role/PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK\",\"FunctionName\":\"ask-custom-PingMe\",\"MemorySize\":\"128\",\"Runtime\":\"nodejs12.x\",\"Description\":\"Alexa Skill Lambda function\",\"Timeout\":\"7\",\"Handler\":\"index.handler\",\"Environment\":{\"Variables\":{\"DYNAMODB_TABLE\":\"askPingMe\"}},\"Code\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"ask-samples-resources\",\"S3Key\":\"code-packages/proactive-events-skill.zip\"},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunction-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:12:29.828Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunction",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "ask-custom-PingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:29.828000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Role\":\"arn:aws:iam::879047331400:role/PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK\",\"FunctionName\":\"ask-custom-PingMe\",\"MemorySize\":\"128\",\"Runtime\":\"nodejs12.x\",\"Description\":\"Alexa Skill Lambda function\",\"Timeout\":\"7\",\"Handler\":\"index.handler\",\"Environment\":{\"Variables\":{\"DYNAMODB_TABLE\":\"askPingMe\"}},\"Code\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"ask-samples-resources\",\"S3Key\":\"code-packages/proactive-events-skill.zip\"},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "DatabaseTable-DELETE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:12:29.616Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseTable",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "askPingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:29.616000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "DELETE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"TableName\":\"askPingMe\",\"AttributeDefinitions\":[{\"AttributeType\":\"S\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}],\"ProvisionedThroughput\":{\"WriteCapacityUnits\":\"5\",\"ReadCapacityUnits\":\"5\"},\"KeySchema\":[{\"KeyType\":\"HASH\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "832ba950-a3dd-11ed-9584-12dec653b89d",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "PingMe",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:10.209000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "The following resource(s) failed to create: [askLambdaFunction]. Rollback requested by user."
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunction-CREATE_FAILED-2023-02-03T16:12:09.166Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunction",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "ask-custom-PingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:09.166000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_FAILED",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource handler returned message: \"Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is in this region: eu-west-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 14b9a860-96e3-4a3b-9a08-c304f4c5619b)\" (RequestToken: 3e646029-0f43-e11c-eb17-cb8ceadba19a, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Role\":\"arn:aws:iam::879047331400:role/PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK\",\"FunctionName\":\"ask-custom-PingMe\",\"MemorySize\":\"128\",\"Runtime\":\"nodejs12.x\",\"Description\":\"Alexa Skill Lambda function\",\"Timeout\":\"7\",\"Handler\":\"index.handler\",\"Environment\":{\"Variables\":{\"DYNAMODB_TABLE\":\"askPingMe\"}},\"Code\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"ask-samples-resources\",\"S3Key\":\"code-packages/proactive-events-skill.zip\"},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunction-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:12:07.314Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunction",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "ask-custom-PingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:07.314000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Role\":\"arn:aws:iam::879047331400:role/PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK\",\"FunctionName\":\"ask-custom-PingMe\",\"MemorySize\":\"128\",\"Runtime\":\"nodejs12.x\",\"Description\":\"Alexa Skill Lambda function\",\"Timeout\":\"7\",\"Handler\":\"index.handler\",\"Environment\":{\"Variables\":{\"DYNAMODB_TABLE\":\"askPingMe\"}},\"Code\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"ask-samples-resources\",\"S3Key\":\"code-packages/proactive-events-skill.zip\"},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunction-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:12:04.938Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunction",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:04.938000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"Role\":\"arn:aws:iam::879047331400:role/PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK\",\"FunctionName\":\"ask-custom-PingMe\",\"MemorySize\":\"128\",\"Runtime\":\"nodejs12.x\",\"Description\":\"Alexa Skill Lambda function\",\"Timeout\":\"7\",\"Handler\":\"index.handler\",\"Environment\":{\"Variables\":{\"DYNAMODB_TABLE\":\"askPingMe\"}},\"Code\":{\"S3Bucket\":\"ask-samples-resources\",\"S3Key\":\"code-packages/proactive-events-skill.zip\"},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunctionRole-CREATE_COMPLETE-2023-02-03T16:12:02.649Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunctionRole",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:12:02.649000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ManagedPolicyArns\":[\"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole\"],\"Policies\":[{\"PolicyName\":\"askLambdaFunctionRolePolicy0\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"dynamodb:GetItem\",\"dynamodb:PutItem\",\"dynamodb:UpdateItem\",\"dynamodb:DeleteItem\"],\"Resource\":[\"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/askPingMe\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\"}]}}],\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"lambda.amazonaws.com\"]}}]},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "DatabaseTable-CREATE_COMPLETE-2023-02-03T16:11:59.818Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseTable",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "askPingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:59.818000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"TableName\":\"askPingMe\",\"AttributeDefinitions\":[{\"AttributeType\":\"S\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}],\"ProvisionedThroughput\":{\"WriteCapacityUnits\":\"5\",\"ReadCapacityUnits\":\"5\"},\"KeySchema\":[{\"KeyType\":\"HASH\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "DatabaseTable-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:11:48.710Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseTable",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "askPingMe",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:48.710000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"TableName\":\"askPingMe\",\"AttributeDefinitions\":[{\"AttributeType\":\"S\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}],\"ProvisionedThroughput\":{\"WriteCapacityUnits\":\"5\",\"ReadCapacityUnits\":\"5\"},\"KeySchema\":[{\"KeyType\":\"HASH\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunctionRole-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:11:47.555Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunctionRole",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "PingMe-askLambdaFunctionRole-9Q23FH86B7GK",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:47.555000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "Resource creation Initiated",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ManagedPolicyArns\":[\"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole\"],\"Policies\":[{\"PolicyName\":\"askLambdaFunctionRolePolicy0\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"dynamodb:GetItem\",\"dynamodb:PutItem\",\"dynamodb:UpdateItem\",\"dynamodb:DeleteItem\"],\"Resource\":[\"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/askPingMe\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\"}]}}],\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"lambda.amazonaws.com\"]}}]},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "DatabaseTable-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:11:47.211Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "DatabaseTable",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:47.211000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"TableName\":\"askPingMe\",\"AttributeDefinitions\":[{\"AttributeType\":\"S\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}],\"ProvisionedThroughput\":{\"WriteCapacityUnits\":\"5\",\"ReadCapacityUnits\":\"5\"},\"KeySchema\":[{\"KeyType\":\"HASH\",\"AttributeName\":\"id\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "askLambdaFunctionRole-CREATE_IN_PROGRESS-2023-02-03T16:11:47.198Z",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "askLambdaFunctionRole",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:47.198000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceProperties": "{\"ManagedPolicyArns\":[\"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole\"],\"Policies\":[{\"PolicyName\":\"askLambdaFunctionRolePolicy0\",\"PolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"dynamodb:GetItem\",\"dynamodb:PutItem\",\"dynamodb:UpdateItem\",\"dynamodb:DeleteItem\"],\"Resource\":[\"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/askPingMe\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\"}]}}],\"AssumeRolePolicyDocument\":{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":[\"sts:AssumeRole\"],\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":[\"lambda.amazonaws.com\"]}}]},\"Tags\":[{\"Value\":\"SAM\",\"Key\":\"lambda:createdBy\"}]}"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "72c4bf70-a3dd-11ed-b99a-0ac8957a8ed1",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "PingMe",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:42.673000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "User Initiated"
        },
        {
            "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "EventId": "6c405a10-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "StackName": "PingMe",
            "LogicalResourceId": "PingMe",
            "PhysicalResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:879047331400:stack/PingMe/6c4478c0-a3dd-11ed-b213-0ad3dd0b0587",
            "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Timestamp": "2023-02-03T16:11:31.903000+00:00",
            "ResourceStatus": "REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS",
            "ResourceStatusReason": "User Initiated"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like a permission issue. You should provide stack output with more context to be able to tell which resource creation is failing but looking at that repo, I would guess it is the lambda creation that is failing as it cannot locate the code source.

If you are trying to run this in us-east-1, then your lambda source code should reside in the s3 bucket in us-east-1, and looks like that's not the case.

If you can download the zip, then you could upload the zip file to a us-east-1 bucket first and then change the ping.yaml to point to the new location.

You might also raise an issue in the github repo and ask for guidance.

Comment: Just posted the stack output.

Comment: How would I upload the lambda source code to US-east-1?

Comment: @JohnHarris - You have an aws account, you could create a bucket and put the zip file there either via gui or using aws cli.

Comment: Well no source code for the project has actually be uploaded. All the readme says to do is just run the script and it'll configure the AWS side of things. All I do after that deploy the code but configure a few things in the json file. As in no skill has actually been deployed yet.

Comment: @JohnHarris - I get what you are saying but you are not doing anything wrong. If they are no longer hosting the lambda source code in us-east-1, lambda service won't be able use the bucket from eu region. You need the repo owner to fix this, hence my suggestion to open an issue in the repo.

Comment: @JohnHarris - See a similar issue reported here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2807 for a different product but same problem.

Comment: So I'm trying to create an access point for us-east-1 in AWS but I get this problem `After you or your AWS admin have updated your IAM permissions to allow s3:CreateAccessPoint action,`

Comment: But I don't think straight up making a bucket will solve this issue because the account just generates one (I think)?

Comment: But also dropping the package into a bucket that I made would mess everything up right? Because the yaml or .sh file in the package sets everything up on the AWS side of things?

Comment: @JohnHarris As long as you have access to source zip, you simply modify the yaml to point it to the correct s3 bucket. Lambda can source it as long it has access to it (in the same region). I am not sure what access point has to do with the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Okay I uploaded it, and do I change the part where it says CodeUri: in the resources section of the yaml file?

Comment: Fixed it thank you so much! It now says CREATE_COMPLETE in AWS.